# Converting a C array to a UIImage (for iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uiimage, nsarray

I currently have some image data in a C array, which contains RGBA data.

```
float array[length][4]
```

I am trying to get this to a UIImage, which it looks like these are initialized with files, NSData, and URLs. Since the other two methods are slow, I am most interested in the NSData approach.

I can get all of these values into an NSArray like so:

```
for (i=0; i<image.size.width * image.size.height; i++){
    replace = [UIColor colorWithRed:array[i][0] green:array[i][1] blue:array[i][2] alpha:array[i][3]];
    [output replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:replace];
}
```

So, I have a NSArray full of objects that are a UIColor. I have tried many methods, but how do I convert this to a UIImage?

I think it would be straight forward. A function sorta like `imageWithData:data R:0 B:1 G:2 A:3 length:length width:width length:length` would be nice, but there is no function as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6):

`imageWithData:` is meant for image data in a standard image file format, e.g. a PNG or JPEG file that you have in memory. It's not suitable for creating images from raw data.

For that, you would typically create a bitmap graphics context, passing your array, pixel format, size, etc. to the `CGBitmapContextCreate` function. When you've created a bitmap context, you can create an image from it using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, which gives you a `CGImageRef` that you can pass to the `UIImage` method `imageWithCGImage:`.

Here's a basic example that creates a tiny 1×2 pixel image with one red pixel and one green pixel. It just uses hard-coded pixel values that are meant to show the order of the color components, normally, you would get this data from somewhere else of course:

```
size_t width = 2;
size_t height = 1;
size_t bytesPerPixel = 4;
//4 bytes per pixel (R, G, B, A) = 8 bytes for a 1x2 pixel image:
unsigned char rawData[8] = {255, 0, 0, 255,  //red
                            0, 255, 0, 255}; //green

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
size_t bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
//This is your image:
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
//Don't forget to clean up:
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: Could you give me some more details on that? An example would be extremely helpful, if you want to. From what I understand, I make a `CGBitmapContextRef` with the `CGBitmapContextCreate` function, but can not find `CGBitmapContextRef` anywhere. I then pass that creation to `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` then pass that to `imageWithCGImage.` Correct?

Comment: Sorry, `CGBitmapContextRef` was incorrect, the `CGBitmapContextCreate` function actually just returns a regular `CGContextRef`. I'll see if I can find a simple example...

Comment: I've added a basic example to the answer.